# forge bim360 custom attributes and Sets

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I’m looking into whether it’s possible to get/set custom attributes in bim360 through Forge, as well as get/set bim360-sets. So far, this doesn’t seem possible. Is this planned for the future, or in any shape or form in (private) beta? Would have a use case for testing this.

[image]

[image]

edit: 
Would also be interesting to know whether the submit for Review and creating a reviewal process from a template would be get/settable through Forge, that might actually align even better with our use case.

[image]

Comment: Checking with Engineering and will update soon once I hear back

Comment: Thanks @BryanHuang, I've edited the question with a third option, which might be even better. I was at the Forge Devcon in Darmstadt but don't think Mikako mentioned this functionality being included in the new beta (or any of the other two).

Comment: @BryanHuang any updates on this?